# How to Allocate memory for PADS_ATTR_INFO

Tags: c++, active-directory

I m stuck and wanna know how to use a pointer `PADS_ATTR_INFO` in `CreateDSObject`.

I can successfully create a user through `CreateDSObject` using `ADS_ATTR_INFO[]`. But I need help in using pointers instead of `ADS_ATTR_INFO`. How to allocate Memory for `PADS_ATTR_INFO`?

Answer (score 0):

```
PADS_ATTR_INFO myAdsAttrInfo = new ADS_ATTR_INFO();
```

Comment: I need to use that in CreateADsObject function. I m getting ADS_BAD_Param exception if i allocate like this